# Maximize comparison score for worst case in n sets

Tags: logic, algorithms, puzzle

Let say i have N sets of same size (max 500) having integers filled with 1 to 9 now I want to find a new set such that when its elements are compared then i should get same element in worst case comparison.

plz see the example
1 2 1 1 3 , 2 2 1 2 1 , 1 2 3 1 1 are 3 sets  now display the set -, 2 , - ,- ,- here 2th element is obvious since it is same in all , so what blank space should be filled with??

if i say 1 2 1 1 1 is my answer set then matching elements are 4 , 3 , 4 respectively for 3 given set, so worst is 3 hence 3 element are matched and 1 2 1 1 1 will be optimal choice and my score is 3.

I am looking to create a special set in which for worst case comparison is maximized and hence my score.

any help ! thnx in advance

Comment: Sets do not have repeated elements. Do you mean multisets or vectors?

Comment: yes i mean vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For clues $c\in\{1,\dots,N\}$ and positions $p\in\{1,\dots,5\}$, let $a_{c,p}$ denote the value that appears in the input.  For positions $p\in\{1,\dots,5\}$ and digits $d\in\{1,\dots,9\}$, let binary decision variable $x_{p,d}$ indicate whether position $p$ takes value $d$.  The problem is to maximize $z$ subject to:
\begin{align}
\sum_d x_{p,d} &= 1 &&\text{for all $p$}\\
z &\le \sum_{p, d:\ a_{c,p} = d} x_{p,d} &&\text{for all $c$}
\end{align}
The first constraint assigns exactly one digit to each position.  The second constraint enforces the max-min objective.

For your sample data, an optimal $x$, with a score of $z=3$, is:
\begin{matrix}
p\backslash d &1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8 &9 \\
\hline
1 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
2 &0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
3 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
4 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
5 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
\end{matrix}
This corresponds to vector $(1,2,1,1,1)$.

Comment: ok thnxx i got it

Comment: I am not able to think over 2 constraint can u plz explain or refer some algo for it

Comment: To solve the formulation I proposed, you would use an integer linear programming solver. Most commercial and open-source solvers use the branch-and-bound algorithm, together with preprocessing, cutting planes, heuristics, and sometimes symmetry detection.

Comment: ok thnx a lot now i got every point

Comment: Glad to help.  Please mark my answer as accepted.